# How to fill password runas command in java

Tags: java, cmd, exec, runas

I have problem inserting password runas in java, i have searched for the answer but not yet get the answers, anyone can help me to solve my problem?

```
Process pr = rt.exec("runas /profile /user:USER \""+command+"\"");
```

Comment: Your question is not very specific. If you want your program to provide the password there’s a simple answer: that’s impossible. `runas` will always access the console.

Comment: @Holger i want to make program that activate adhoc connection in win 8 with java, because normally it can be activate using command prompt with run as administrator. this is the command
`netsh wlan start host`

since the command mus be run as administraotr, i must add _runas_ command before these command, but if i use command it will ask the password, so the _netsh_ command failed to run.

and the problem is how to insert _runas_ command's password
thanks before.

Comment: As said, you can’t. The only way to start a process using a different account I know is to use the native Windows API. So you might use JNA, for example.