# How to start a Windows `runas` process with Java?

Tags: java, windows, process

I have a Windows `runas` command that works perfectly when typed at the command line, but **not** when invoked from my Java program through `Runtime.exec()`.  The code looks almost exactly like this:

```
// Create the process.
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    String.format(
        "runas /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\\OtherUser \"%s\",
        command));

// Enter the password.
try (OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
     PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream)) {
    printWriter.printf("%s\n", password);
    printWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

// Wait for the process to terminate.
process.waitFor();
```

I see the password prompt, `Enter the password for DOMAIN\OtherUser:`, and then the process immediately terminates with an exit value of 1.

As an *experiment*, I moved the `process.waitFor();` above the code that enters the password, expecting the process to *hang* at the password prompt.  But, the process does **not** hang.  It still terminates with 1!  (And then the attempt to enter the password causes `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`.)

The same code will successfully run processes that don't require input (and don't go through `runas`), and also successfully provides input to `sudo --stdin` on Linux.

I've studied many similar questions with no luck.

The Windows in question is Windows 7 and the Java in question is Java 8.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Impossible?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789115/how-to-fill-password-runas-command-in-java

Answer (score 1):

OK, looks like you can't do this:

[How to fill password runas command in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789115/how-to-fill-password-runas-command-in-java)

The reason being that the Windows `runas` command does not read from `stdin`, but directly from the console.